# using the tree command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Good day everyone,

just starting out in this forum ^^

I was able to run the tree command in the command window and was able to export the data to a file

however, for users that are slower / don't know, I wanted to create a batch file,

where all they put is the main path or url, and the batch will create the file for them,

i am having problems implementing the "tree command" in the batch

```
@echo off
color 0A
Title Export data

echo write the path you want to see the folder structure for:
set /p path=">>"

cd /d %path%

tree /a >>results.xls
pause
exit
```

thanks for your time,

Comment: What exactly is the "problems" you're having "implementing" the tree command?

Comment: you want xls file from three command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I see the issue here.  You are getting the user to input something into the variable `PATH`, but that is a system variable that is used to locate executable files when you don't specify a location.

One such file is the `tree.com` that you are trying to run.  It resides in the windows System32 directory.  That directory is normally in the `PATH` variable, but you just replaced it.

Call it something else (*eg* `mypath`).

```
set /p mypath=">>"
cd /d "%mypath%"
tree /a >> results.xls
```

Comment: WOW... Good eye, I never would have seen that. !:)!

Comment: thanks a ton!! i had no idea, seems something realy simple, lol,

I also wanted to ask, can i choose where the file gets saved or it gets saved in the %CD% and then I have to use the move command?

Comment: Yes you can just specify a directory: *eg* `tree /a > c:\temp\results.txt`.  Make sure to enclose with double-quotes if the path contains spaces.  Notice I used a single `>`.  I figure you probably want to replace the file if it exists, rather than append to it.